# I Can integrate wordpress registration with my php script?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, registration

Wordpress can share registration with a php script?

or I can?

create singup from FB on the main site, but also, add the same code (FB SINGUP) in the php script (on sudomain )

This could work to achieve a unique registration, or at least a portion.?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can has cheeseburger?

Comment: back in the days we tried stuff before we asked if it´s possible...but the very simple answer to this question would be "yes, you can". not entirely sure if i know what you mean though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user sign up in your website you have basic data whether by some text input or from external link such as FB. Next step is set sessions and cookie and you have choice to limit cookies to root or subdomain and so on. If it's not answer of your question share more details, please.